# How do i export my database in php using lighttpd and mysql, setup by palapa webserver?

Tags: php, mysql, lighttpd

How do you export and import a database in lighttpd and mysql in php? They were setup by Palapa Web Server on android? I have tried mysqldump but it does not work.

```
$backup="mysqldump -h localhost -u root -padminadmin tapify > backup.sql";
passthru($backup);
```

and

```
exec($backup);
```

Comment: any specific reason why you want to do this in php and not on shell? (assuming it is one time). Is it a regular backup job?

Comment: Can't you connect to the MySQL server from another computer and use mysqldump on it ?

Comment: this server runs when there is not an internet connection

Comment: i found out that i cant use mysqldump with palapa webserver

Comment: @AnshuPrateek yes ultimately i am syncing an online database with the local db in case the internet goes out because the app displays info that is absolutely necessary to the clients customers

Comment: the cms i built allows them to update on the fly while the program is running even if it is offline so it always checks online first then reverts to local if offline as well when they are saving. it syncs if it can in either direction depending on the timestamp

Comment: Maybe you should take a look to phpmyadmin/adminer procedures.